# Change HTML language from en-US in to ar in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm using this code snippet on wordpress but i don't know why it dosn't work

```
 <?php 
 
 $locale = 'en-US';


 define( 'WPLANG', 'en-US', 'myfunction' );
 function myfunction(){
 if ( is_page( array( 'test', 'partners', 'management' ) ) ) {
     
    add_filter( 'locale', function() {
        return 'ar';
    });
 
 } else {
      echo 'page is not true';
 }  
 }
 ?>
```

I tried using this code snippet but it looks like that I'm using an old method that make it doesn't work

Comment: Since you didn't describe the need and expectation from that code snippet, I can't provide you with better information, However, you're using [define](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) function wrong by passing the function name as 3rd args. Please check the function documentation and add the need and your expectation with code snippet.

Comment: @VijayHardaha I'd say the title gives a fairly clear description of the expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the locale on specific frontend pages then the code will be like this:

**Note: this code should be placed in your theme's `functions.php` file**

```php
/**
 * Override locale for specific frontend pages.
 *
 * @param string $locale Current locale.
 */
function vh_custom_change_locale( $locale ) {
    // Validate for specific frontend pages.
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_page( array( 'test', 'partners', 'management' ) ) ) {
        $locale = 'ar';
    }

    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'vh_custom_change_locale' );
```

I am unsure if you do have this `$locale` variable there, it might a global variable but I am not aware of it since I never used it so can't really say whether you should use it or not.

```php
$locale = 'en-US';
```

This `WPLANG` define line should be in your `wp-config.php` file not in the theme's `functions.php`

```php
define( 'WPLANG', 'en-US' );
```